# Declaration of characters and Strings

Tags: java

Declaration of a character:

```
char ch = '';
```

When I do this i am getting the error *'empty character literal'*.

Declaration of a String:

```
String str = "";
```

I see no error in doing that to a String.

The question is, why doesn't a similar error show up for the declaration of a String, or why declaration of empty character generating such error where empty string is getting passed

Comment: A string consists of zero or more characters.  A cardboard box can contain zero or more oranges, and can be empty, but there's no such thing as an empty orange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string is an array of characters. By passing it nothing, i.e. making it equal to `""` you basically make an empty array which is fine. But `char` is a primitive type hence it cannot be "empty". The closest you can get is setting it equal to `'\0'` which is the `null` character.

Answer (score 3):

String is a set of chars and String str=""; contains no chars(read: empty string)
but if you want to have Char variable it must have some value. '' means no value.

Comment: it can't be null; `char` is a primitive and must always have a value (although it can be unassigned, in which case it can not be accessed)

Comment: @Ratul no. Java strings are not like C strings. Java strings may contain nulls (hex `00`) - their length is managed in a separate field to the backing `char[]`

Comment: @RatulSharker in Java end of string isn't marked by null (ASCII 0) character. Instead it is implemented as `char[]` array, and all arrays have predefined length.

Answer (score 1):

String is a class in Java with its own syntax and methods. It accepts strings in double quotes. And a string is actually an Array of characters and is hence acceptable to be posted empty.
Char on the other hand is a data type and cannot be left undetermined. It needs to specified NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to read through the Java tutorial documentation hosted on Oracle's website whenever you are in doubt about anything related to Java.

Basically char is a thing you put in a box, and a string is a box to hold all those things. You can have an empty box but not a non-existant thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here char represents the 16-bit integer value of the character in quotes. Refer this [table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the values.
There is no representation number for "empty/no character".
In case of String refer their source [code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java). You can see that empty string is represented internally by 0 size char array. So String internally does not have magical representation of empty/no character. For "" String class does not allocate any space per se